# Does this code violate open-closed principle?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, jackson, jackson-databind

I want to know if the below code is violating open closed principle.

`Animal` is a parent class of `Dog`, however `Animal` has jackson annotations that help `ObjectMapper` (de)serialize the classes. Anyone who extends `Animal` will have to edit only annotations present on `Animal` to make sure (de)serialization works as intended leaving the class untouched.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ 
  // all subclasses
  @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog")
})
public abstract class Animal {
    // fields, constructors, getters and setters
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Theoretical point of view

[Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) like the whole [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) is `Utopia`. We should continually upgrade our code in that direction but probably we will never end up there because this is not possible. Let's read below articles to see how classical `getters` and `annotation` constructs can be debatable.

1. [Printers Instead of Getters](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/04/05/printers-instead-of-getters.html)
2. [Java Annotations Are a Big Mistake](https://www.yegor256.com/2016/04/12/java-annotations-are-evil.html)

### Practical point of view

Like every practical programmer I like to use good tools to solve problems instead of implementing something new myself. When I am asked to serialise given model to `JSON` files I am checking whether it is:

1. Open-source
2. Fast
3. Under active development
4. It is easy to use

When we are talking about `Jackson` and it's annotations, I think, we can find golden middle way between theory and practice. And this is thanks to [`MixIn`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature. You can separate model from the way how it is serialised to `JSON`. Of course when you add new class which extends base class you need to change `MixIn` `interface` with annotations but this is a price we need to pay.

### Edit or Why I forgot to answer a question?

Sorry, I forgot to answer a question whether above example violates `Open/Closed principle` or not. First, get definition from [`Wikipedia` article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle):

> A class is closed, since it may be compiled, stored in a library,
>   baselined, and used by client classes. But it is also open, since any
>   new class may use it as parent, adding new features. When a descendant
>   class is defined, there is no need to change the original or to
>   disturb its clients.

Above example violates `When a descendant class is defined, there is no need to change the original` part. Even if we use `MixIn` there is a need to change other part of app. Even more, if your solution uses `annotations` in 99.99% of cases you violate this part because there is a need to configure somehow functionality which is hidden behind them.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer the basic question because, in my opinion, from theoretical point of view: _violates_, and from practical: _no_ because `cost` is not to high. But everyone should define `cost` for himself.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! There's another solution apart from `MixIn`. 
```@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
public abstract class Animal {
    // fields, constructors, getters and setters
}
@JsonTypeName(value = "Dog")
public class Dog extends Animal {

}```

Comment: From the same `Wikipedia`: "A module will be said to be closed if [it] is available for use by other modules. This assumes that the module has been given a well-defined, stable description". This solution is not `well-defined` and `stable` because you can remove `JsonTypeInfo` annotation from root and all descendants will be broken suddenly. You can not force descendants to have this annotation and can not force root class to have it because interface/class is not broken. It contains the same methods. `API` is the same but something does not work. Problem of more than 50% of questions on `SO`.

Comment: I agree that SOLID code is the promised land. I agree that we should strive to get there. I disagree that it is not possible.

Comment: @aridlehoover, When I wrote `is not possible` I meant the whole project. Of course, we can implement some parts of the project in `SOLID` mode but the whole one is not possible or really hard to achieve goal.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it does. The idea of the open-close principle is to make objects extendable without having to modify them internally. Since any new child of `Animal` would have to modify it to work properly, it breaks the principle.

Answer (score 0):

Open/closed means a class should be open for extension, but closed for modification.

In other words... if you want to change the behavior of a class you should extend it in some way, but you should not modify it.

You can extent a class by

- creating a subclass. This is usually done using e.g. the template method pattern.
- defining an interface that class A uses so that it's behavior can be extended by passing it another instance of that interface, e.g. a strategy pattern. A good real life example is a [`TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-), because it's sorting behavior can be changed without modifying `TreeSet` itself.

From my point of view the `@JsonSubTypes` annotation is not part of the behavior of the `Animal` class. It changes the behavior of another class - the object mapper. Thus it is not really a violation. Not really means that even if you don't change the behavior, you have to touch the `Animal` class and recompile it.

It is a really weird design of the annotation. Why did that json developers not allow you to put an annotation on the subclass, e.g. like JPA does when it comes to hierarchy mapping. See [DiscriminatorValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorValue.html)

It is a strange design that a supertype references subtypes. 
Abstract types should not depend on concrete ones. In my opinion that is a principle that should always be applied.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a different perspective! Going by the definition, open-closed is violated in all cases when the source code of abstract class is modified. Are annotations and documentation of class part of source code?